# Cleanest approach to Unit test for thread safety of a method in java

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, singleton, completable-future

I have been trying to write a unit test for lazy-instantiated singleton class to demo that this implementation is thread unsafe. Following is the code for its getInstance method:

```
private static DateUtil dateUtilInstance;

public static DateUtil getInstance() {
    if (null == dateUtilInstance) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        dateUtilInstance = new DateUtil();
    }
    return dateUtilInstance;
}
```

For testing this scenario for thread un-safety, I tried few approaches such as -

1. implementing "callable" class for having a callback for thread classes to easily write assertion. I found this approach a bit unclean for unit test as it involved creating of 2 separate classes to test the thread unsafe scenario
2. tried implementing "runnable" class as well - but similar take as above along with fact that I could not provide a callback there.
3. Using "CompletableFuture" to run the method in async way. Here is the unit test code for this approach:

```
    @Test
    void shouldVerifyThatClassInstantiationIsThreadUnsafe() {
        var task1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(DateUtil::getInstance);
        var task2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(DateUtil::getInstance);
        var instance1 = task1.join();
        var instance2 = task2.join();

        assertNotEquals(instance1, instance2);
    }
```

The test runs fine if I run it individually, but it fails when I run with all other tests at class level. I am novice to concept of threading, so I have some questions around this:

1. Is this approach of using `completableFuture` correct for testing the multi-threaded scenario or am I confusing / mixing the concepts?
2. Why is above unit test working when ran individually but failing when ran with other tests? Can someone please help me understand the rationale behind it?
3. Any other better approach to test this thread-safety scenario?

PS: I have already browsed through other similar questions here that were coming in suggestions, but they were not addressing the approach for unit test that I have shared and needed clarity on.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?  You can't prove that a function is thread safe from a test-  all we'd know is that the test you wrote didn't happen to trigger it a problem-  that doesn't mean it's thread safe.  Change the timing by nanoseconds and it could fail.  You'd also be left with a flaky test-  sometimes it would fail, sometimes it wouldn't, depending on the way the OS schedules things.  This isn't something you ever do.

Comment: I was just trying to do this for demo purpose. By running this method in separate threads, i wanted to demo how this is thread unsafe. Thank you for providing the reasoning behind why this approach is not right. So if I understand correctly, you are suggesting that cases like this cannot be demo-ed via some test case, runner method, etc. at all and should not be written to avoid any flaky tests?

Comment: Ok, if you want to demo that it isn't thread safe, that you can do.  Launch it in a hundred threads, and test the results.  It's proving that it is thread-safe that isn't possible.  You also wouldn't use this as part of a unit test suite.  But a proof of concept that it can cause problems is definitely possible.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that. Can you please elaborate more on how i can build a small POC around this?

Answer (score 1):

It maybe because CompletableFuture.supplyAsync() could be submitting the task to a threadpool which has only a single available thread to process.  So, task2 will only be executed after task1 has complete.

This might happen when you're running the unit tests with other tests. Without knowing more, impossible to tell.

However,  you could try creating your own threadpool with enough threads to execute everything in parallel. Try this:

```
    @Test
    void shouldVerifyThatClassInstantiationIsThreadUnsafe() {
    ExecutorService myThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    var task1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(DateUtil::getInstance,myThreadPool);
    var task2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(DateUtil::getInstance,myThreadPool);
    var instance1 = task1.join();
    var instance2 = task2.join();

    assertNotEquals(instance1, instance2);
    myThreadPool.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I have understood your thought process and reasoning behind using separate threadpool. I am new to using this approach and will learn more about it. However, for the time being, i tried to run this unit test with 2 threadpools. However this is failing - both individually as well as when ran with other tests.